# Lenovo Legion Slim 5 reboots when change brightness from keyboard

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, lenovo, brightness

I have Lenovo Legion Slim 5 laptop with Ryzen 7 and RTX 4060 (2023) and Ubuntu 22.04.2

**Problem:** when I change display brightness with a keyboard hotkeys, laptop spontaneously reboots.

Brightness is changing, but this spontaneously causes reboots. Changing brightness from dropdown menu is working fine and safe.

I suppose that it happens due to hybrid gpu setup and thus drivers issues.
I've tried to force using nvidia from grub and blacklisting nouveau.
Looking forward for your advices.

Update:
Looks like a driver issue. Does it look OK?

```
inxi -Gxx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: Lenovo driver: nvidia v: 535.86.05 pcie:
speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 ports: active: none empty: DP-9,HDMI-A-1,eDP-2
bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:28e0
  Device-2: AMD vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel pcie:
speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: eDP-1
empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, DP-5, DP-6, DP-7, DP-8 bus-ID: 06:00.0
chip-ID: 1002:15bf
  Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech Integrated Camera type: USB
driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-3:2 chip-ID: 30c9:00ac
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9
driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia
unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 4096x2560 s-dpi: 120
  Monitor-1: eDP res: 4096x2560 dpi: 302 diag: 407mm (16")
  OpenGL:
renderer: GFX1103_R1 (gfx1103_r1 LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-26-generic)
v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```

Update_2: After several driver and Ubuntu updates problem has gone.
Brightness control works fine for me.

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Well, there are strange repeated lines in log ´kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller´ and after that lines reboot happens. No special errors were found in journalctl.
I suppose, that there are a conflict of drivers and that causes kind of low-level situation that causes instant reboot.